# wWinMainCRTStartup and wWinMain are filled with uninitialized memory

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, ghidra

I have a PE executable (32 bit) GUI program and I tried to reverse engineer it. I opened it in Ghidra and discovered the `entry` calls `wWinMainCRTStartup`. However, when I checked `wWinMainCRTStartup` all the bytes are filed with `??` and when I tried to disassemble it Ghidra says `Can't disassemble uninitialized memory`. I'm confused... if the memory is uninitialized then how can the program run at all? But the program does run.